# Unable to integrate Google Mobile Ads in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-ads-api

I've been struggling to integrate google ads in the flutter app. It keeps crashing.

Installed version: google_mobile_ads: ^0.12.1+1

I've updated the manifest too with the ads meta-data

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="<AD-CODE>" />
```

Whenever I try to debug the code on the emulator. I get these errors in the console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): Process: com.example.kavya_digest, PID: 23372
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * to find your app ID.                                                       *
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7135)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6675)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6592)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * to find your app ID.                                                       *
E/AndroidRuntime(23372): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzt.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:24)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7130)
E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    ... 10 more
Exited
```

Comment: from what can I see you don’t have the correct ID it says `E/AndroidRuntime(23372): * Invalid application ID.` and you should check this link ( https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest ) to properly add your ID to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @LuisFernandoScripcaru Hi! thanks for pointing out the mistake. It has two formats on the instruction screen and I used the wrong one. https://prnt.sc/12d8gpb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get application id create admob app then create ad units for your app and then you get both appid and ad units to get start.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```